# Cronjob is creating 2 different files

Tags: cron

I'm running test.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
date >> /home/admin/scripts/cron.log.txt ; echo "app01 hat erfolgreich den cronjob in test.sh ausgefuehrt" >> /home/admin/scripts/cron.log.txt
```

on 2 diferent servers with a crontab -e entry on both:

```bsh
# Alle 10 Min., laut cron.log erfolgreich!
*/10 * * * * sudo sh /home/admin/scripts/test.sh
```

That's to say, they are identical. One one server I'm getting everything in cron.log.txt, on another server it's creating cron.log.txt with date entry, and cron.log.txt? with the echo entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably caused by the `sudo`. You can't use `sudo` in a crontab (or indeed in any script) because, where would it get the password from? Instead, if you need to run the shell with `sudo` privileges, you put it in the `root` crontab: `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: Nah, it was because I was too stupid to transfer test.sh with WinSCP as text , instead I did as binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you transfered the file `test.sh` with WinSCP as text and not binary file.